# Xuggler/Java Thumbnail from Video

Tags: java, grails, video, thumbnails, xuggler

I'm building an app in Grails, but I am well versed in Java also.  I need to display thumbnails of video files, and then when the user clicks on a thumbnail, open that video in a player.  (Like Youtube).

What I am thinking is, when the user posts the video, I'll use xuggler to grab a thumbnail, and save that along with the video file itself.

**Question 1:** Is that a good design?

I am not familiar with xuggler.

**Question 2:** Is there some way to grab a thumbnail from input stream as the user is uploading?  Otherwise, I am going to write the file, and then grab the thumbnail from that as described [here](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/ws/workingcopy/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xuggler](http://blog.xuggle.com/) seems like the way to go.

I'm doing something similar at the moment. I'm opting to download the entire file payload before attempting to assume I was given a video.

I've built a similar system in PHP and users submitting Windows Movie Maker project files was a real issue.

`application/octet-stream` was a very common content-type from machines that didn't know file type associations